# Java8 Lambda can I generate new list of object

Tags: java, jpa, lambda, java-8

I would like to know if there is a way to reduce this method, since the only thing that changes is the counter to obtain the value.

```
List<Vo> response = daoImpl.getresult(query).stream.map(
  t-> new Vo( t.get(0,Object.class),

    t.get(1,Object.class),

    t.get(2,Object.class),

    t.get(3,Object.class),

    t.get(4,Object.class), 

    t.get(5,Object.class),

    t.get(6,Object.class), new vo2(

        t.get(7,Object.class),

       t.get(8,Object.class)

))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My classs Vo

```
Public class Vo(){

private Object param1;
private Object param2;
private Object param3;
private Object param3;
private Object param4; 
private Object param5; 

private Object param6;
private Vo2 info;

--Getter and setter
 }
```

My classs Vo2

```
Public class Vo2 (){

   private Object param7;
   private Object param8;

   --Getter and setter

}
```

the get method belongs to the dao class which returns a list of type Tuple, this method get value of the element specified position in the result tuple, the firs position is 0

I would like to know if the code could be reduced using IntStream.

I made an attempt but I don't know how the constructor could do and go from position 0 to 6 I belong to an object and from 7 to 8 is another

```
List<Tuple> list =daoImpl.getresult(query);

list.stream().map(v-> new Vo(IntStream.range(0,6).mapToObj(h-> v.get(h,Object.class)))). collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my interpretation of what you want

- this creates two arrays of objects from `t.get`.
- the first array will be argument one of the `Vo` class constructor.
- the second array will be an argument to the  `Vo2` class constructor.
- then the resulting `Vo2` class will be argument two of the `Vo` class constructor.
- they are packaged into Object arrays for creating the `Vo` object.

You may have to do some casting of the arrays in the constructor and also iterate over the arrays to assign the individual fields (or just keeping them as arrays might be easier).

```
List<Vo> response = daoImpl.getresult(query).stream

        .map(t -> new Object[][]{
           // create objecsts for 0 thru 6
           IntStream.rangeClosed(0,6)
                   .mapToObj(i->t.get(i, Object.class)).toArray(Object[]::new),
           // create objects for 7 thru 8              
           Intstream.rangeClosed(7,8)
                   .mapToObj(i->t.get(i,Object.class)).toArray(Object[]::new)}).
           // create the Vo object             
           map(ob->new Vo(ob[0], new Vo2(ob[1]))).collect(Collectors.toList());

class Vo {
    
    private Object param0;
    private Object param1;
    private Object param2;
    private Object param3;
    private Object param4;
    private Object param5;
    
    private Object param6;
    private Vo2 info;
    
    public Vo(Object[] objects0Thru6, Vo2 vo2with7and8) {
        // do something with these.
    }
    
//--Getter and setter
}
```

Comment: Excellent it was very helpful I thank you

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
List<Vo> response = daoImpl.getresult(query).stream.map(
t-> new Vo(
    IntStream.range(0, 9)
        .map(i -> t.get(1,Object.class))
        .toArray()
))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can use an `IntStream` to generate the 9 constructor arguments of `Vo`.